# PHP Warning: Missing Dependencies need fix

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

my site wordpress and I am using query monitor that discover this error

> Missing Dependencies  daftplug-instantify-pwa-admin   wp-content/plugins/daftplug-instantify/pwa/admin/assets/js/script-pwa.min.js
> jquery, daftplug-instantify-admin (missing)

is this fatal error ?
how to fix it ?
best regards

Answer (score 0):

I read the developer's comment regarding this issue, that this error is not a fatal error and can be ignored. He said it was an unnecessary warning.

Comment: Pleas add the link as reference in case the readers and the person who is asking wanted to confirm the information. It also will be important to make your response more trustworthy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).